# How to add indexes to Rails DB?

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, migration, indexing

When adding an index to a table, is it as simple as writing a migration with:

```
add_index(:column_name)
```

And for the down method

```
remove_index(:column_name)
```

Are there any surprises I need to be aware of?

Working in Rails 3.07, Postgres. On Heroku.

Thanks.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do I get the feeling this is a trick question?

Yes, it's that simple.  No, there are no surprises, although very few people are ever glad of having made such a promise. :-)